# java jar -D option passing multiple external config files

Tags: spring-boot

I have two configuration files that have to be read using spring boot application, however, only the first configuration property file is resolved (`external_application.properties`) , later one (`queries_config.properties`) is not getting detected any issue in passing in the command line.

```
java -Dexternal.app.properties=file:external_application.properties -Dqueries.config.properties=file:queries_config.properties -jar testsnapshot.jar
```

Comment: i merged the config file but i want to segregate as separate one..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot so you can use

> java
> -Dspring.config.location=file:external_application.properties,file:queries_config.properties

[source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar)

Comment: will check and get back

Comment: i have posted my answer, thanks for your suggestion which helped me to digout more

Answer (score 0):

```
I did like below which resolved over all problem..

java -Dspring.config.location=classpath:file:///C:\Users\configfiles\ -jar testsnapshot.jar

secondly to lookup for external config 

@Component
@PropertySource(value = "${spring.config.location}queries_config-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties("query")
public class QueriesConfig {

}

@Component
@PropertySource(value = "${spring.config.location}external_application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties("query")
public class ExternalConfig {

}
```